# Can Sonatype Nexus show Gradle dependency information?

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

Looking at the following URL: -

https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjunit%7Cjunit%7C4.12-beta-1%7Cjar

Clicking on Gradle/Grails, provides the format for gradle for the build.gradle file.

**Can this be done for nexus?**

See the image below: -

[image]

I've set up my Nexus repository and would like to be able to see differing formats.

Is this possible with Nexus or would I need another repository management tool?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. Perhaps file a feature request.